# Axial vs equatorial attack of Grignard reagent on dioxan-5-one and dithian-5-one

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stereochemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

How to account for the diastereoselectivety (axial vs equatorial attack) of these reactions?
[image]

Comment: Isn't that very advanced for 1st year? (from your profile). Think about the outcome when S or O are plain carbons and then try to find which one O or S doesn't "behave" as expected.  Clearly the 2 different results have to come from different transition states. How can $\ce {MeMgI}$ interact with the starting materials?

Comment: Oops, that's a mistake. The second year started this week. MeMgI can coordinate to the oxygen and then attack from above. On the other hand it doesn't coordinate so strongly to sulfur and the Me- adds to the sterically less demanding equatorial position?

Comment: Nevertheless, the addition to dioxan-5-one doesn't seem to be in agreement with Felkin-Ahn's model, and chelation is not an option in this rigid system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_induction - so it's Anti-Felkin product?

Comment: Also, you should add info like this in your comments to your question

Comment: I don't see how it is Anti-Felkin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution in Fleming: Molecular Orbitals-Reference edition:

> The dioxan-5-one is attacked by nucleophiles in the gas
>   phase from the equatorial direction, because of electrostatic repulsion from the fraction of negative charge
>   carried by the two oxygen atoms in the ring, as Houk had predicted. The selectivity is not particularly high
>   (67:33), because the usual torsional strain is still present, enhanced in this case by the shorter C—O bond
>   lengths making the ring less puckered, and increasing the dihedral angle by which the carbonyl oxygen atom
>   is pushed below the neighbouring C—H bonds. In solution, however, the ketone is attacked
>   from the axial direction, just like cyclohexanones. Evidently the solvent insulates the charge on theincoming nucleophile from the electrostatic repulsion, the torsional strain remains high and there are no axial
>   substituents hindering axial attack.The sulfur atoms in the dithia analogues are less electronegative than the oxygen atoms in the acetals but the axial lone pairs bulge further up, and are not heavily solvated. However, the carbonyl group is
>   displaced even further down by the changes in bond length and bond angles from having two C—S bonds in
>   the ring. The one effect makes axial attack less favourable, and the other makes equatorial attack less
>   favourable. In the event both solution and gas phase reactions take place with a strong preference for
>   equatorial attack.

Comment: You couldn’t have presented that in any less readable way, could you? (Sorry if I sound aggressive here but remember that your question (and answer) will remain as references for future visitors, and this type is likely to put people off.)

Comment: Maybe it could be better presented but still deserves an up-vote